# How to scroll down and perform a click in a button with espresso testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-espresso

I have this app that I am testing where I need to login, then it goes to another activity, and then it goes to another activity where I can logout. The problem is that my logout button is on the bottom of my `ScrollView` and is not seen in the screen and espresso does not find the button. I need to scroll first and then click the button. Can you tell me how can I scroll and then click the button?

```
@Before
    public void init() {
        // Specify a valid string.
        loginText = "something";
        passwordText = "something";
    }

    @Test
    public void loginAction() {

        mBrowserActivityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(MainActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

        // Type text and then press the button.
        onView(withId(R.id.editText_username))
                .perform(typeText(loginText), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.editText_password))
                .perform(typeText(passwordText), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.button_login)).perform(click());

        Activity activity = mBrowserActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000);

        onView(withId(R.id.button_left)).perform(click());

        Activity activity2 = mBrowserActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000);


        onView(withId(R.id.button_logout)).perform(click()); **//does not recognize**

        Activity activity3 = mBrowserActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000);
        assertNotNull(activity3); //To see if activity 2 (Profile) is opened
```

**This is the error log:**

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed
>   because the target view does not match one or more of the following
>   constraints:
>       at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 3):

```
onView(withId(R.id.button_logout)).perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

If the view you are working with is located inside a ScrollView (vertical or horizontal), consider preceding actions that require the view to be displayed (like click() and typeText()) with scrollTo(). This ensures that the view is displayed before proceeding to the other action:

onView(...).perform(scrollTo(), click());

Note: scrollTo() will have no effect if the view is already displayed so you can safely use it in cases when the view is displayed due to larger screen size (for example, when your tests run on both smaller and larger screen resolutions).

You can check their documentation: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/basics/index.html#performing-an-action-on-a-view

Comment: The doesnt help me. It says that it doesnt find the button_logout id

Comment: and the link is death